# shell script to return lines between two matching line in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

My file is containing below data:

```
Line 1: FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing file.

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing file

FILE_READER: TPT19220 Directory scan completed.  2 files processed.

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19220 Directory scan completed.  3 files processed.
```

I want unix script which will return only below data

```
FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing

FILE_READER: TPT19220 Directory scan completed.  3 files processed.
```

I want unix script which will return all lines between last line containing "TPT19220" and second last line containing.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -n '/TPT19220/,/TPT19220/{p}' yourfile | sed '1d'
```

Comment: That's correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

With awk you can say "give me all lines between a line matching pattern 1 and a line matching pattern 2 (inclusive)" with `awk '/pat1/,/pat2/'`.

Maybe this does the trick (depends on your exact start/end pattern requirements):

```
awk '/processing$/,/Directory scan completed/' inputfile
```